# Почему не получается правильно завершить поток? (Qt/C++)

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Пишу многопоточное сетевое приложение на QT. На сервере есть заданное фиксированное кол-во потоков. При подключении клиента создается объект для работы с этим клиентом и помещается в поток. При отключении клиента объект испускает сигнал, при котором сервер должен правильно остановить именно этот поток.
Но в моменте остановки и удаления потока выдает следующую ошибку:
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
Видимо, я плохо понимаю, как надо правильно останавливать поток.

Создание нового работника и потока для него:

```
Workers[IndFreePlace] = new Worker(this->nextPendingConnection()->socketDescriptor(), IndFreePlace);
Threads[IndFreePlace] = new QThread(this);
Workers[IndFreePlace]->moveToThread(Threads[IndFreePlace]);

connect(Threads[IndFreePlace], &QThread::started, Workers[IndFreePlace], &Worker::StartWork);
connect(Workers[IndFreePlace], &Worker::StopThread, this, &Server::DisconnectClient);
Threads[IndFreePlace]->start();
```

Завершение работы с клиентом (DisconnectClient):

```
delete Workers[ThreadID];
Workers[ThreadID] = nullptr;

Threads[ThreadID]->quit();
Threads[ThreadID]->wait();
delete Threads[ThreadID];
Threads[ThreadID] = nullptr;
```

Без строки Threads[ThreadID]->wait() выдает ошибку, которую я написал выше. С ней же просто зависает и все. Код "полезной" нагрузки:

```
void Worker::StartWork()
{
    mUserSocket = new QTcpSocket;
    mUserSocket->setSocketDescriptor(mSockD);
    connect(mUserSocket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &Worker::StopWork);
    qDebug() << "Check\n";
}
```

Работник посылает сигнал серверу об остановке потока:

```
void Worker::StopWork()
{
    qDebug() << "Client #" << mID << " disconnected\n";

    mUserSocket->close();
    delete mUserSocket;
    mUserSocket = nullptr;
    emit StopThread(mID);
}
```

Comment: Вы вызываете delete Workers[ThreadID]; в функции самого воркера. То есть, такой себе камикадзе. Дальше продолжать?

Comment: Май бэд, надо было указать, что функция DisconnectClient находится в Server'е.
Проблему уже исправил, сейчас буду писать ответ)

Comment: удаляйте массив, но не виджеты. Ну и, по хорошему, есть походящие контейнеры для того, чтобы с массивами не возиться...

Answer (score -2):

Проблему решил методом тыка.

1. Одна из ошибок была в том, что я закрывал соединение и удалял сокет еще в потоке, в слоте Worker::StopWork. Когда я вынес это в деструктор, оставив слоту Worker::StopWork только функцию отправки сигнала, все стало хорошо.
2. Вторая ошибка заключалась в том, что я сначала удалял объект, находящийся в потоке, а затем закрывал поток и удалял его. Делать нужно было все ровно наоборот: сначала закрыть поток, дождаться его завершения, удалить его и только после этого удалить сам объект, который подчистит за собой все в деструкторе.

Comment: Вообще лучше поток не удалять - пусть живет, Вы же не один раз подключаетесь к сокету..

Comment: для того, что бы не думать, удалять или нет, можно просто использовать пул потоков. А ручками это делать...  С другой стороны, если потоки живут достаточно долго (допустим хотя бы несколько минут), то создание/удаление потока ничего не испортит. А код, который ручками будет "делать пул потоков", может слишком усложнить все.